# How to create pagination with 3 argument in url using codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using Codeigniter 2.2 and I try to build pagination ask Codeigniter guide and it is work perfectly for me when I used as url below

```
$pages_num: is the amount of pages for view.
http://localhost/Codeigniter2.1.4/public_html/page/$pages_num
```

But I get error when I add one argument for url
as code below I try to find it 3 weeks ago But I have not solution Please 
 Notes: number 2 is id categories and number 4 is amount of pagination view

```
http://localhost/Codeigniter2.1.4/public_html/cat/2/4
```

Here is my code in controller

```
$this->load->model('frontend/categories_m');
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results('job');

            $perpage = 2;
        if ($count > $perpage) {
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('cat/2');
            $config['total_rows'] = $count;
            $config['per_page'] = $perpage;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        } else {
            $this->data['pagination'] = '';
            $offset = 0;
        }
        $this->db->limit($perpage, $offset);

        $this->data['job_cat'] = $this->job_m->get_job();
        $this->data['subview'] = 'cat';
        $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
```

Here is for view:

```
 <?PHP if ($pagination): ?>
 <section class="pagination">
 <?PHP echo $pagination; ?>
 </section>
 <?PHP endif; ?>
```

Please help

Sorry I can't post images here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With codeigniter pagination, the default link structure is as below

```
http://website/pages/getPagesViaAjax/3/5
```

Here pages is controller, getPagesViaAjax is function inside it and 3 is a parameter for category id and 5 will be the pagination count(i.e. offset)

in this case my pagination config is something like

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('getPagesViaAjax/3');
$offset = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

So basically your offset will be the last argument and i.e. 5(available at segment 4) in this case. So prior to firing your query to model, please check the offset.

Comment: It can be or not if I can't used Ajax because I don't understand ajax much now sorry Sir if you have some ajax relate this please let me some source code

Comment: In current code "getPagesViaAjax" doesn't require you have ajax based call for loading controller. Although I have used ajax based pagination for such scenario where offset was available using($this->uri->segment(4)). Here you can just treat it as a function like "cat" as you have used. Anyway if you want a source code of ajax based pagination then you can download it here : https://github.com/k10gaurav/codeigniter-ajax-pagination

Comment: You Know I can't sleep one week till now it was solved by your help 

I really thanks you very much sir 
everythink is working now
Thanks

Comment: It's pleasure for me! If my answer has helped you please show your love by accepting the answer and vote so that other users get benefited.

Comment: Ok then just accept the answer(below the vote icon). Vote up/down requires some specific reputation.

Comment: anyway @ happy coding :)

Comment: Now I found Vote sorry that I can't find it before and When I have ability to vote I will do for you